# How to create a native module in React Native

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native

I'm trying to follow this guide here to create a native module in React Native.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup

When you create the native module these are the setup instructions.

```
cd react-native-my-library/example
yarn
cd ios
pod install # required starting with React Native 0.60
cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

I don't have an `example` subfolder and there is also no pod file installed in the ios directory so `pod install` just gives me this error.

```
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

It's also creating my project with an older verison of react native. It's using `react-native: 0.59.10.`

The current version I have installed is `react-native: 0.61.5`.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.15.3.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well yesterday, here's one [reply from the repo owner](https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module/issues/266#issuecomment-594323958). Append the following to podfile will do

```
pod 'react-native-my-library', :path => '../react-native-my-library.podspec'
```

At the same time I realized podfile is not really necessary unless your module required other depedendency to be installed? Otherwise, I just build on top of .xcworkspace and link to my project. Ta-da, works fine!

** One thing to keep in mind is that, .xcworkspace is not able to compile due to the complain of missing React/***.h